# Correct way to switch vertex / color buffers OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to use a common function I wrote called box() to draw multiple boxes in OpenGL 4.5. It seems to work reasonably well, and I can get it to make multiple boxes.

However, I'm having trouble drawing what will become the bottom of a cylinder. I'm trying to generate the faces by making multiple triangles. The triangles share a vertex at the center, and the other vertices are based on the angle.

I know you can do this with a triangle fan or strip, but I need to be able to specify normals for each vertex later on, too.

My problem is, when I render this scene, I just see a single, lonely, triangle floating about. This brings up two major questions:

1) Where am I going wrong? I verified the x and z coordinates are correct via printf output just to see what was getting generated.

2) What is the correct method for swapping the vertex and color buffers out when drawing completely different shapes. For instance, I need to be able to eventually call box(), make some transforms, call cylinder(), etc.

```
//compiled with g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -Wall -Werror -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -lGLEW


// Link statically with GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC

// Headers
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace glm;

//Glut
#include <GL/glut.h>

// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

#include "cube.h"

#define Cos(x) (cos((x)*3.1415927/180))
#define Sin(x) (sin((x)*3.1415927/180))

GLuint MatrixID;
glm::mat4 MVP;
GLuint vertexbuffer;
GLuint colorbuffer;
GLuint shaderProgram;

high_resolution_clock::time_point t_start;

static const GLchar* vertexSource = {
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;"
        "\n"
        "// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.\n"
        "out vec3 fragmentColor;"
        "// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.\n"
        "uniform mat4 MVP;"
        "\n"
        "void main(){   "
        "\n"
        "   // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position\n"
        "   gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);"
        "\n"
        "   // The color of each vertex will be interpolated\n"
        "   // to produce the color of each fragment\n"
        "   fragmentColor = vertexColor;"
        "}"
    };

static const GLchar* fragmentSource = {
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders\n"
        "in vec3 fragmentColor;"
        "\n"
        "// Ouput data\n"
        "out vec3 color;"
        "\n"
        "void main(){"
        "\n"
        "   // Output color = color specified in the vertex shader, \n"
        "   // interpolated between all 3 surrounding vertices\n"
        "   color = fragmentColor;"
        "\n"
        "}"
    };

void checkError(int line)
{
    GLint err;

    do
    {
        err = glGetError();
        switch (err)
        {
            case GL_NO_ERROR:
                //printf("%d: No error\n", line);
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
                printf("%d: Invalid enum!\n", line);
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
                printf("%d: Invalid value\n", line);
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
                printf("%d: Invalid operation\n", line);
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
                printf("%d: Invalid framebuffer operation\n", line);
                break;
            case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                printf("%d: Out of memory\n", line);
                break;
            default:
                printf("%d: glGetError default case. Should not happen!\n", line);
        }
    } while (err != GL_NO_ERROR);
}



int loadShaders()
{
    GLuint vertexShader;
    GLuint fragmentShader;

    // Create shaders
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        checkError(__LINE__);
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
      checkError(__LINE__);  
    // Create program and link to shaders
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "color");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
  checkError(__LINE__);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    //TODO: add error checking and return code.
    checkError(__LINE__);
    return 0;
}

glm::mat4 Projection;
glm::mat4 View;
glm::mat4 Model;

void box()
{
    MVP        = Projection * View * Model; 

    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles
    Model = glm::mat4(1.0);
}


typedef struct __vertex
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
} vertex_t;

typedef struct __color
{
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
} color_t;

void cylinder()
{
    int theta = 0;
    int dt = 15;
    int i = 0;

    vertex_t *pVert;
    color_t *pColor;

    // Bottom face
    // 360 / dt = number of triangles
    // Multiplied by 3 verticies per triangle
    // Multiplied by 3 floating points to describe each vertex
    GLfloat *vertex_buffer_data = new GLfloat[360 / dt * 9];
    GLfloat *color_buffer_data = new GLfloat[360 / dt * 9];

    for (theta=0; theta < 360; theta += dt, i += sizeof(vertex_t) / sizeof(GLfloat))
    {
        pVert = (vertex_t *)(vertex_buffer_data + i);
        pColor = (color_t *)(color_buffer_data + i);

        printf("theta: %d\n", theta);
        pVert[0].x = 0;
        pVert[0].y = 0;
        pVert[0].z = 0;

        pVert[1].x = Cos(theta);
        pVert[1].y = 0;
        pVert[1].z = Sin(theta);
        printf("Vertex 1: %f %f %f\n", pVert[1].x, pVert[1].y, pVert[1].z);

        pVert[2].x = Cos(theta + dt);
        pVert[2].y = 0;
        pVert[2].z = Sin(theta + dt);
        printf("Vertex 2: %f %f %f\n", pVert[2].x, pVert[2].y, pVert[2].z);

        pColor[0].r = 1.0f;
        pColor[0].g = 1.0f;
        pColor[0].b = 1.0f;

        pColor[1].r = Cos(theta)*Cos(theta);
        pColor[1].g = Sin(theta)*Sin(theta);
        pColor[1].b = Cos(theta)*Cos(theta);

        pColor[1].r = Cos(theta + dt)*Cos(theta + dt);
        pColor[1].g = Sin(theta + dt)*Sin(theta + dt);
        pColor[1].b = Cos(theta + dt)*Cos(theta + dt);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 360 / dt * 9, vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 360 / dt * 9, color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    MVP = Projection * View * Model;

    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 360 / dt * 9); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles

    Model = glm::mat4(1.0);
    delete[] vertex_buffer_data;
    delete[] color_buffer_data;

}

void display()
{

    // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
    Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // Camera matrix
    View       = glm::lookAt(
                                glm::vec3(0,3,0), // Camera is at (4,3,-3), in World Space
                                glm::vec3(0,0,0), // and looks at the origin
                                glm::vec3(0,0,1)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                           );
    //auto t_now = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //float time = duration_cast<duration<float>>(t_now - t_start).count();



    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    Model = glm::mat4(1.0);
    cylinder();

    /*
    Model =  glm::scale(Model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)) * glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    box();


    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(0.5, 2.5, 0.0)) * glm::scale(Model, glm::vec3(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)) * glm::rotate(Model, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    box();
        */
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int width,int height)
{
    //  Set viewport as entire window
    glViewport(0,0, width,height);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void idle()
{
    //glutPostRedisplay();
}
int init(int argc, char** argv)
{
    t_start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition (140, 140);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL Application" );
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    loadShaders();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "MVP");

    // Load models
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_cube_vertex_buffer_data), g_cube_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_cube_color_buffer_data), g_cube_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                                // size
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );



    return 0;   
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (init(argc, argv) != 0) { return -1; }

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

cube.h is just a buffers of vertices and colors:

```
#ifndef __CUBE_H__
#define __CUBE_H__

    static const GLfloat g_cube_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // One color for each vertex. They were generated randomly.
    static const GLfloat g_cube_color_buffer_data[] = { 
        0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
        0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
        0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
        0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
        0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
        0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f,
        0.597f,  0.770f,  0.761f,
        0.559f,  0.436f,  0.730f,
        0.359f,  0.583f,  0.152f,
        0.483f,  0.596f,  0.789f,
        0.559f,  0.861f,  0.639f,
        0.195f,  0.548f,  0.859f,
        0.014f,  0.184f,  0.576f,
        0.771f,  0.328f,  0.970f,
        0.406f,  0.615f,  0.116f,
        0.676f,  0.977f,  0.133f,
        0.971f,  0.572f,  0.833f,
        0.140f,  0.616f,  0.489f,
        0.997f,  0.513f,  0.064f,
        0.945f,  0.719f,  0.592f,
        0.543f,  0.021f,  0.978f,
        0.279f,  0.317f,  0.505f,
        0.167f,  0.620f,  0.077f,
        0.347f,  0.857f,  0.137f,
        0.055f,  0.953f,  0.042f,
        0.714f,  0.505f,  0.345f,
        0.783f,  0.290f,  0.734f,
        0.722f,  0.645f,  0.174f,
        0.302f,  0.455f,  0.848f,
        0.225f,  0.587f,  0.040f,
        0.517f,  0.713f,  0.338f,
        0.053f,  0.959f,  0.120f,
        0.393f,  0.621f,  0.362f,
        0.673f,  0.211f,  0.457f,
        0.820f,  0.883f,  0.371f,
        0.982f,  0.099f,  0.879f
    };

#endif // __CUBE_H__
```

Comment: There are at least 3 or 4 small problems in the `cylinder()` function. Nothing you shouldn't be able to figure out by stepping through the code in a debugger, and looking at values. For example, the loop increment looks wrong, since you're generating 3 vertices in each loop iteration, but only increment by one vertex.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep on it. Is the approach to swapping / binding the vertex and color buffers the best way to go about that portion of the code where I change to the cylinder verticies?

Comment: You should definitely not calculate and upload the data in each frame. Just do that once and bind the appropriate buffers when you want to draw them (as it is done in init for the cube).